# A light blur effect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I would like to get a light blur effect , in which you still can somehow recognise the image, or even adjust it .

I used to have the Apple one :

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
alphaView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
```

Which is not really "light" , but is very strong so you cant see the image anymore.

I would rather not using external 3rd classes, because from my experience they turned to be problematic.

I also remember Apple used to have a class called : `UIIMAGE+BLUR`, before the `UIVisualEffectView` which let you adjust things. 
Is it still valid and acceptable by the App Store ?

Comment: Regarding the usage of `effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight`: that does not refer to the intensity of the blur, but the hue of the resulting image. Same goes for the other two styles, they all blur in the same way, only the hue varies.

Comment: thanks a lot, so practically what can i do to get my desired effect ?

Comment: Not yet sure, I am looking into it for a bit, what I just told you was just what came up reading the docs for a few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two other options I know of.

One is to use the Accelerate framework and do it manually (I think this is the `UIIMAGE+BLUE` you refer to): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UIImageEffects/Introduction/Intro.html

The easier option is to use CoreImage's Gaussian Blur. There's some sample code in the Question here: [CIGaussianBlur image size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20531938/78496)

Comment: Yes! the second was what i looked for! is that still valid and acceptable by the Appstore? i know the UIVisualEffect came instead of this "low level" one.

Comment: It's not deprecated so I don't see why not. That thread sounds more like a bug in the Beta rather than any indication it was being removed.

Comment: UIVisualEffect was added to expose a few private Apple APIs that were used in iOS 7. It wasn't intended to replace CoreImage or Accelerate, as they both offer more options (albeit sometimes with longer processing time as a tradeoff)