# How can I make UIBlurEffectStyleLight more subtle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm applying the blur effect to my cells `backgroundView` like so:

```
// Setup imageView
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
                
// create effect
UIBlurEffect *blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
                
// add effect to an effect view
UIVisualEffectView *effectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blur];
effectView.frame = self.view.frame;
                
// add the effect view to the image view
[imageView addSubview:effectView];
cell.backgroundView = imageView;
```

The problem is that the blur effect this applies is way too strong, you can barely see the image:

[image]

Is there any way to apply a more subtle blur effect? I've tried `UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight` and `UIBlurEffectStyleDark`, but those just change the brightness, not how strong the blur effect is.

Comment: u can alter its alpha value.

Comment: @Mr.T I've tried this, it seems to dim the image rather than blur.

Comment: did u look into this https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A light blur effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565313/a-light-blur-effect)