# GussianBlur image with scaleAspectFill

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use Gaussianblur on an image, but also i want to use my imageview scalemode's `scaleAspectFill`.

I am blurring my image with following code:

```
func getImageWithBlur(image: UIImage) -> UIImage?{
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    guard let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") else {
        return nil
    }
    let beginImage = CIImage(image: image)
    currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    currentFilter.setValue(6.5, forKey: "inputRadius")
    guard let output = currentFilter.outputImage, let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else {
        return nil
    }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
}
```

But this is not working with `scaleAspectFill` mode.

[image]

They are both same images. But when i blur the second image, as you can see it is adding space from top and bottom. What should i do for fit well when using blur image too?

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531938/cigaussianblur-image-size. The combination of `aspectFill` and `clipsToBounds` is concealing from you what is _really_ happening. :)

Comment: Alternatively, don’t use CoreImage at all and just place a visual effect view between the image and the label. E.g. if presenting white text, I might use a dark dimming view of `UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))`.

Comment: Visual effect is blurring too much and doesn’t have any radius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply a `CIGaussianBlur` filter, the resulting image is ***larger*** than the original. This is because the blur is applied to the edges.

To get back an image at the original size, you need to use the original image extent.

Note, though, the blur is applied both *inside* and *outside* the edge, so if you clip only to the original extent, the edge will effectively "fade out". To avoid the edges altogether, you'll need to clip farther in.

Here is an example, using a `UIImage` extension to blur either **with** or **without** blurred edges:

```
extension UIImage {

    func blurredImageWithBlurredEdges(inputRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

        guard let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let beginImage = CIImage(image: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        currentFilter.setValue(inputRadius, forKey: "inputRadius")
        guard let output = currentFilter.outputImage else {
            return nil
        }

        // UIKit and UIImageView .contentMode doesn't play well with
        // CIImage only, so we need to back the return UIImage with a CGImage
        let context = CIContext()

        // cropping rect because blur changed size of image
        guard let final = context.createCGImage(output, from: beginImage.extent) else {
            return nil
        }

        return UIImage(cgImage: final)

    }

    func blurredImageWithClippedEdges(inputRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

        guard let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let beginImage = CIImage(image: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        currentFilter.setValue(inputRadius, forKey: "inputRadius")
        guard let output = currentFilter.outputImage else {
            return nil
        }

        // UIKit and UIImageView .contentMode doesn't play well with
        // CIImage only, so we need to back the return UIImage with a CGImage
        let context = CIContext()

        // cropping rect because blur changed size of image

        // to clear the blurred edges, use a fromRect that is
        // the original image extent insetBy (negative) 1/2 of new extent origins
        let newExtent = beginImage.extent.insetBy(dx: -output.extent.origin.x * 0.5, dy: -output.extent.origin.y * 0.5)
        guard let final = context.createCGImage(output, from: newExtent) else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(cgImage: final)

    }

}
```

and here is an example View Controller showing how to use it, and the different results:

```
class BlurTestViewController: UIViewController {

    let imgViewA = UIImageView()
    let imgViewB = UIImageView()
    let imgViewC = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 8
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

        ])

        [imgViewA, imgViewB, imgViewC].forEach { v in
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            v.clipsToBounds = true
            // square image views (1:1 ratio)
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        guard let imgA = UIImage(named: "bkg640x360") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!")
        }

        guard let imgB = imgA.blurredImageWithBlurredEdges(inputRadius: 6.5) else {
            fatalError("Could not create Blurred image with Blurred Edges")
        }

        guard let imgC = imgA.blurredImageWithClippedEdges(inputRadius: 6.5) else {
            fatalError("Could not create Blurred image with Clipped Edges")
        }

        imgViewA.image = imgA
        imgViewB.image = imgB
        imgViewC.image = imgC

    }

}
```

Using this original `640x360` image, with `200 x 200` image views:

[image]

We get this output:

[image]

Also worth mentioning - although I'm sure you've already noticed - these functions run ***very*** slowly on the simulator, but very quickly on an actual device.

Comment: Wow, that's a great explanation. Thank you so much, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that the convolution kernel of the CIFilter is creating additional data as it applies the blur to the edges of the image. The CIContext isn't a strictly bounded space and is able to use area around the image to fully process all output. So rather than using output.extent in createCGImage, use the size of the input image (converted to a CGRect).

To account for the blurred alpha channel along the image edge, you can use the CIImage.unpremultiplyingAlpha().settingAlphaOne() methods to flatten the image before returning.

```
func getImageWithBlur(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    guard let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") else { return nil }

    let beginImage = CIImage(image: image)
    currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    currentFilter.setValue(6.5, forKey: "inputRadius")

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

    guard let output = currentFilter.outputImage?.unpremultiplyingAlpha().settingAlphaOne(in: rect) else { return nil }
    guard let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, from: rect) else { return nil }

    print("image.size:    \(image.size)")
    print("output.extent: \(output.extent)")

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)

}
```