# CIGaussianBlur shrinks UIImageView

Tags: swift, uikit

Using `CIGaussianBlur` causes `UIImageView` to apply the blur from the border in, making the image appear to shrink (right image). Using `.blur` on a `SwiftUI` view does the opposite; the blur is applied from the border outwards (left image). This is the effect I’m trying to achieve in `UIKit`. How can I go about this?

I've seen a few posts about using `CIAffineClamp`, but that causes the blur to stop at the image boarder which is not what I want.

[image]

```
  private let context = CIContext()
  private let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!

  private func createBluredImage(using image: UIImage, value: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
         let beginImage = CIImage(image: image)
         
         filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
         filter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
         
         guard
             let outputImage = filter.outputImage,
             let cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)
         else {
             return nil
         }
         
         return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
     }
```

Comment: You want the image to blur beyond the frame and “bleed” into the area around it?

Comment: Exactly correct.

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon - you may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60550960/6257435

Comment: Using beginImage.extent does prevent the image from shrinking, but the edge blur is not nearly as pronounced.

Answer (score 0):

When I used `CIGaussianBlur` I wanted my output image to be contained inside the image frame, so I used `CIAffineClamp` on the image before applying the blur, as you describe.

You might need to render your source image into a larger frame, clamp to that larger frame using CIAffineClamp, apply your blur filter, then load the resulting blurred output image. Core Image is a bit of a pain to set up and figure out, so I don’t have a full solution ready for you, but that’s what I would suggest.

Comment: This would always constraint the blur to be within the larger container and not just free to expand however it wants.

Comment: As a workaround, Ive just expanded the view by 20pts in all directions since the shrinking seems to be 1:1 with the blur radius. However, I’m not a fan of this solution either.